# UITableViewCell cell reuse and UILabel auto-layout dynamic sizing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm working with a subclassed UITableViewCell and I need to align a UILabel's text to the Top Left all while using Auto Layout.  I realize reading up that sizeToFit really shouldn't be used with Auto Layout and I'd like to avoid it, and somehow use a constraint.  Basically the label's text is reset every reuse of the cell so the sizing would need to be dynamic on reuse.

Here's the Lazy initializer label inside the subclassed cell:

```
- (UILabel *)commentsLabel {

    if (_commentsLabel == nil) {

         _commentsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
         [_commentsLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
         _commentsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
         _commentsLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
         _commentsLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 100;
    }

    return _commentsLabel;
}
```

There are auto-layout constraints being set on the label (commentsLabel is a subView added to self.customView on the cell subclass):

```
[self.customView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-locationToTopPadding-[locationLabel(locationHeight)]-locationToCommentsPadding-[commentsLabel]-commentsToBottomPadding-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:@{
                                                                                  @"locationToTopPadding":@(locationToTopPadding),
                                                                                  @"locationHeight":@(locationHeight),
                                                                                  @"locationToCommentsPadding":@(locationToCommentsPadding),
                                                                                  @"commentsToBottomPadding":@(commentsToBottomPadding)
                                                                                  }
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary]];

[self.customView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[thumbnailImageView]-[commentsLabel]-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:@{@"commentsWidth":@(commentsWidth)}
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary]];
```

setting just:

```
self.commentsLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 100;
```

doesn't seem to work although that is mentioned in most answers.

currently have this implemented but not seeing any results.
[UILabel sizeToFit doesn't work with autolayout ios6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6)

another answer I tried.
[UILabel sizeToFit only works with AutoLayout turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922803/uilabel-sizetofit-only-works-with-autolayout-turned-off)

I feel that I'm just missing 1 constraint that can be added in addition to the constraint above but the programmatic constraints I try to add don't work or throw an exception.  I'm working completely in code there are no xibs.

ETA: tried setting a height constraint inside the existing vertical constraint line:

like suggested here: [Dynamically change UILabel width not work with autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438627/dynamically-change-uilabel-width-not-work-with-autolayout)

in the vertical constraint line above making it:

```
-[commentsLabel(>=30@900)]-
```

I've messed around with the height value and priority value and nothing changed.

ETA:  making some progress, I think it has to do with the bottom padding of the label, tried this and some of the labels are aligned correctly some aren't:

```
->=commentsToBottomPadding-
```

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Answer (score 1):

solution in the event any one else runs into the same issue with a UITableViewCell and a custom Label that changes dynamically:

```
-[commentsLabel]->=yourBottomPadding-
```

put that in the vertical constraint

call this in the viewController after you set the text:

```
[cell updateConstraints];
```